# Unable to merge dex in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

Hi I am developing app in flutter. When I am trying to build flutter then I am getting an error `Unable to merge dex`.

### app build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.xyz"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

### module build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.51'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Does anyone know how to resolve it in flutter ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding this in app build.gradle

```
android {
defaultConfig {
   multiDexEnabled true
 }
}
```

change

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0' 
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
```

And also open the project in Android studio and 
clean,
rebuild or simply run flutter clean command

Answer (score 0):

take this steps :

1. clean the project by running `flutter clean`
2. rebuild using `flutter build` or run using `flutter run`.

i hope this will help .

Answer (score 0):

Following this [link](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/#0) solved a very similar issue for me.

** I did not not have to set multiDexEnabled to true

First I set dependencies in my pubspec.yaml to

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cloud_firestore: ^0.8.2
```

and ran `flutter packages get` in my IDE's terminal.

Also I had to change the minimum target SDK version:

1. Open android/app/build.gradle, then find the line that says
   minSdkVersion 16.
2. Change that line to minSdkVersion 21.
3. Save the file.

This alone may fix your problem; however I had to also do the following because some of my dependency versions were mismatched.

I had to open `android/app/build.gradle`, then add the following line as the last line in the file:
`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

Next, I had to open `android/build.gradle`, then inside the buildscript tag, add a new dependency:

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
       // ...
   }

   dependencies {
       // ...
       classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'   // new
   }
}
```

After this my app finally ran on the android emulator.

The [link](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/#6) has a more complete walkthrough if you get stuck.